# How can I keep my autistic kid from making an unhygienic mess?

Tags: potty-training, hygiene, diaper, autism, special-needs

I have a four and a half year old boy with juvenile autism, almost no verbal language and intellectual disability. He doesn't understand the concept of going potty yet, and is still wearing diapers both for number one and number two.

We can handle having to change him, but the trouble is he  pulls out his penis and pees, takes off his diaper or sticks his hand in his diaper after doing number two, and makes a horrible mess of both himself and his surroundings.

You'd think we'd be able to stop him, but he's so fast we just need to turn our heads for a few seconds and he'll have done it again.

The only method we've found that keeps him from being able to do this is to dress him in tight fitting onesies with the zipper in the back, but those are hard to find in shops and makes him look even more "special needs" than he already does.

I would be very happy if anyone had any alternative methods to share!

Comment: large onesies. http://www.special-need-products.com/bodysuit-onesie.html#sthash.f3wx1Jj1.dpbs

Comment: I didn't know about that site, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My daughter seems to like shoving her hand down her diapers. She is a scratch fan so she just tears up her skin unless we block her with a onesie. They make them for larger kids too: [www.special-need-products.com](http://www.special-need-products.com/bodysuit-onesie.html#sthash.f3wx1Jj1.dpbs)

They look like normal shirts so he shouldn't appear strangely to anyone. Just that when he does decide to give the toilet a try he will need extra help for a while.